# Perl Yawriter XML

Tags: xml, perl

I am using Perl Yawriter to generate XML from a DB and write to file.  Usually, it creates a new file as such:

```
my $ya = XML::Handler::YAWriter->new(AsFile => "grp.xml");
```

However, I now have need to use an already existing file, however I do not understand the nomenclature used within the documentation.

The documentation states:

Output IO::File 
This option tells YAWriter to use an already open file for output, instead of using $ya->{Strings} to store the array of strings. It should be noted that the only thing the object needs to implement is the print method. So anything can be used to receive a stream of strings from YAWriter.

However, despite many permutations tried, I cannot work out how this should be written. Does anybody have any experience with this so they can advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean to append to an existing file, this ought to work:

```
my $fh = IO::File->new('filename', '>>');
my $ya = XML::Handler::YAWriter->new( Output => $fh );
```